# Chequear varios inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Teniendo varios inputs, si los quisiera chequear todos con un mismo patron ¿Cómo se podría hacer?
un ejemplo

```
var input1 = $("#inp1");
var input2 = $("#inp2");
var input3 = $("#inp3");
var input4 = $("#inp4");
var inputX = $("#inpX");


if (input1.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')

if (input2.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')

if (input3.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')

if (input4.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')

if (inputX.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')
```

La única forma que veo viable esto es trabajando con clases

```
var allInputs = $(".classInput");

if (allInputs.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')
```

¿Alguien conoce alguna otra forma de agrupar todos los elementos para poder trabajar con ellos?

Comment: Usando clases es de los mejores métodos, pero claro te puedes ver con problemas si agregas otro tipo de condiciones al <input>, lo que deberías hacer es usar lo que has propuesto (usando clases) y después detectar la id del input que está vacío, sin necesidad de poner una condición en cada caso, y hacerlo todo en una misma función.

Comment: ¿Por qué no aprovechas la validación HTML5? Poniendo el atributo required a los inputs automáticamente te valida que no estén vacíos. Ésto es mucho más práctico, ha no ser que desees compatibilidad con navegadores reviejos.

Comment: Ya se que se puede validar con required o el atributo pattern, pero esto es un ejercicio simplificado de lo que tengo y lo he puesto para aprender y ver distintas soluciones. Además que justamente no es validación lo que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea una función genérica de verificación:

```
var no_puede_estar_vacio = function(input)
{
    if (input.val().length < 1)
        alert('No puede estar vacio.');
};
```

Y verifica todos los inputs de golpe con esa función usando [`forEach`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp):

```
[$("#inp1"), $("#inp2"), $("#inp3"), $("#inp4"), $("#inpX")].forEach(no_puede_estar_vacio);
```

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar si alguno de los elementos cumple o no cierta condición, puedes utilizar [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some).

Ejemplo

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {

  // capturas la clase y aplicas `some` 
  var bool = $('.in').toArray().some(function(el) {
    return $(el).val().length < 1
  });

  if (bool) {
    console.log("al menos uno de los elementos esta vacio");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="in" name="a">
<input type="text" class="in" name="b">
<input type="text" class="in" name="c">
<input type="text" class="in" name="d">
<input type="text" class="in" name="e">
<button id="btn">Tocame</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recogerlos todo en un array y aplicar una funcion de validación única para todos los campos individualmente.

Te pongo un ejemplo, junto a otro modo, donde tenemos un array con los ids de los inputs, recorremos el array, buscamos el input con ese ID y, si existe el input, recogemos el valor y llamamos a una función de validación para dicho valor.

```js
var inputs = [];
inputs.push($("#inp1"));
inputs.push($("#inp2"));
inputs.push($("#inp3"));
inputs.push($("#inp4"));
inputs.push($("#inpX"));

//O también:
//var inputs = [$("#inp1"),$("#inp2"),$("#inp3"),$("#inp4"),$("#inpX")];

var validarInput = function(input){
  if (input.val().length < 1)
    alert('No puede estar vacio.')
}

for(i in inputs){
  if(inputs.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    input = inputs[i];
    validarInput(input);
  }
}
//////////////////////
//Otro modo que me gusta mas puede ser:
//////////////////////

var ids = ["inp1","inp2","inp3","inp4","inpX"];

var validarValue = function(val){
  if(!val || val.length <1){
    alert("No puede estar vacio"); 
  }
}


//Recorremos todos los ids
for(i in ids){
  if(ids.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    id = ids[i];
    //Por cada ID buscamos su input
    var input = $("#"+id);
    //Si no hay input, no lo podemos validar
    if(input){
      //Llamamos a la función para validar el valor
      validarValue(input.val());
    }
  }
}
```